# Ошибка в процессе установки Flask. Python 2.7.13. Windows 7

Tags: python, flask, python-2.7

Командная строка:

[image: cmd]

```
c:\phttp\ard\Scripts>pip.exe install Flask
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\phttp\ard\lib\site.py", line 703, in 
    main()
  File "c:\phttp\ard\lib\site.py", line 670, in main
    virtual_install_main_packages()
  File "c:\phttp\ard\lib\site.py", line 611, in virtual_install_main_packages
    if os.path.exists(tk_dir):
  File "c:\phttp\ard\lib\genericpath.py", line 26, in exists
    os.stat(path)
TypeError: stat() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str

Код:

```
main()

def _script():
help = """\
%s [--user-base] [--user-site]

Without arguments print some useful information
With arguments print the value of USER_BASE and/or USER_SITE separated
by '%s'.

Exit codes with --user-base or --user-site:
  0 - user site directory is enabled
  1 - user site directory is disabled by user
  2 - uses site directory is disabled by super user
      or for security reasons
 >2 - unknown error
"""
args = sys.argv[1:]
if not args:
    print("sys.path = [")
    for dir in sys.path:
        print("    %r," % (dir,))
    print("]")
    def exists(path):
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            return "exists"
        else:
            return "doesn't exist"
    print("USER_BASE: %r (%s)" % (USER_BASE, exists(USER_BASE)))
    print("USER_SITE: %r (%s)" % (USER_SITE, exists(USER_BASE)))
    print("ENABLE_USER_SITE: %r" %  ENABLE_USER_SITE)
    sys.exit(0)

buffer = []
if '--user-base' in args:
    buffer.append(USER_BASE)
if '--user-site' in args:
    buffer.append(USER_SITE)

if buffer:
    print(os.pathsep.join(buffer))
    if ENABLE_USER_SITE:
        sys.exit(0)
    elif ENABLE_USER_SITE is False:
        sys.exit(1)
    elif ENABLE_USER_SITE is None:
        sys.exit(2)
    else:
        sys.exit(3)
else:
    import textwrap
    print(textwrap.dedent(help % (sys.argv[0], os.pathsep)))
    sys.exit(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
_script()
```

Comment: чтобы люди с похожей проблемой могли бы найти этот вопрос, сообщение об ошибке следует в виде текста добавлять, а не картинки (если не знаете как текст в Windows консоли скопировать, задайте отдельный вопрос).

Comment: вероятно проблема к flask не имеет отношения. Если вы любой другой пакет, который у вас не стоит попробуете поставить, то что происходит?

Comment: перед попыткой установки Flask установил virtualenv подобным образом, установка прошла нормально, а вот Flask начал выдавать ошибки

Comment: Обнаружил, что из папки с python pip работает нормально, а из папки созданной под проект как раз и выдаёт эти ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была конечно не у Flack. Из под powershell всё заработало.